# Volume of a torus using the washer method

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

If the circle $(x - b)^2 + y^2 = a^2 (0 <a< b)$ is revolved
about the y-axis, it generates a doughnut-shaped solid
called a torus. Find the volume of this torus by the
washer method.

Let's use the washer method, the upper half of the circle is

$$x = \sqrt{a^2-y^2} + b $$

the lower half:
$$x = b - \sqrt{a^2-y^2}$$

then:

$$dV = \pi[(\sqrt{a^2-y^2} + b)^2-(b - \sqrt{a^2-y^2})^2]dy = 4b\sqrt{a^2-y^2}$$

what are the limits of integration?

$$V = \int_0^{a+b}4b\sqrt{a^2-y^2}dy$$?